Error in importing MambaConfig and MambaModel from transformers (huggingface) in a cluster
I am trying to import MambaConfig, MambaModel from the library transformers
from transformers import MambaConfig, MambaModel

In particular I am running the script on a cluster where I have to activate the virtual enviroment and load the module.
The module that I am loading are the following:
module load CUDA/11.7.0
module load Python/3.10.4-GCCcore-11.3.0
module load PyTorch/1.13.1-foss-2022a-CUDA-11.7.0

and the error that I am obtaining is the following:
ImportError: libcudart.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Iam not sure if is due to the enviroment where I might installed bad some prerequirements or to the incompatibility to module that I have loaded, which should not be because I check the version required.
I have already trying what I found on stackoverflow but its not working.
Thanks to evryone for the answer
